# requestAnimationFrame, setInterval e setTimeout

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de entender mais qual a natureza dessas três funções citadas acima. Qual o principal objetivo para cada uma? Se tratando de animações, qual a melhor opção para alterações no DOM ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que já usei

requestAnimationFrame É mais para jogos ou animações, é como um set interval  só que sem problemas com a diferença de MS de um computador para outro, veio junto com o CSS3 e HTML5
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

SetInterval é o método para executar uma ação acada X milisegundos
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

SetTimeout é o método que roda um método APENAS UMA VEZ após X milisegundos
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Dependendo da animação é bom você usar css3

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp